# Scanning a file with getBytes:range:?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm currently scanning a binary file with the following code:

```
 while (offset < headerLength) {
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        [bookData getBytes:buffer range:NSMakeRange(0 + offset, 4)];
        NSString *output = [NSString stringWithCString:buffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        if ([output isEqualToString:@"EXTH"]) {
           ...
        }
        offset++;
 }
```

However, I suspect that's not the correct way, because it is quite slow. How to search for a specific string then?

GOOD BUT SLOW:

```
while (offset < headerLength) {
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    [bookData getBytes:buffer range:NSMakeRange(0 + offset, 4)];

    if (buffer[0] == 'E' && buffer[1] == 'X' && buffer[2] == 'T' && buffer[3] == 'H') {
        //run my stuff
        break;
    }
    offset++;
}
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
```

Doesn't run my stuff

```
FILE * handle = fopen ([path UTF8String], "r");
while (1) {
    fseek(handle, ++offset, SEEK_SET);
    if (fgets(buffer, 4, handle)) {
        if (buffer[0] == 'E' && buffer[1] == 'X' && buffer[2] == 'T' && buffer[3] == 'H') {
            //doesn't run my stuff
            break;
        }
    }
}
fclose(handle);
```

Comment: If your file is "not so large" (read: if it can fit as a whole in RAM), why don't you read it in a single `contentsOfFileAtPath:` call and use `NSString`'s search instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IO is slow, so I'd read in large chunks and avoid reading small chunks from a stream inside a loop. getBytes: makes a copy from the NSData object's bytes into your buffer, so you want to avoid doing that frequently too. Here is some untested pseudocode, assuming you have your NSData object to start off with:

```
const char *bytes = [bookData bytes];
while (offset < headerLengh - 4)
{
    if (bytes[offset] == 'E' && bytes[offset + 1] == 'X' && bytes[offset + 2] == 'T' && bytes[offset + 3] == 'H')
    {
        //...
    }
    offset++;
}
```

I will note that there exist faster/more complicated algorithms such as boyer-moore for this type of search, but this should do for now.

I'd also advise against creating many NSString objects inside the loop. If you want to, you can create a NSString from your NSData object, and retrieve substrings inside the loop appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a full-fledged `NSString` on each iteration, you could just compare the raw bytes directly:

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
while (offset < headerLength) {
   [bookData getBytes:buffer range:NSMakeRange(0 + offset, 4)];
   if (buffer[0] == 'E' && buffer[1] == 'X' && buffer[2] == 'T' && buffer[3] == 'H') {

       ...
   }
   offset++;
}
```

This is assuming your buffer holds 4 `char`s, of course.

Also, I don't believe it's needed to clear the memory on each iteration with memset. Just once before the loop will do.

Comment: I've replaced the code as you suggested but nothing changes in terms of performances

Comment: Nothing changes? You're directly comparing low-level bytes instead of creating thousands of `NSString`s and nothing changes?

Comment: Have you tried the low-level C functions for reading into files (`fopen`, `fseek`, `fgets`)?

Comment: Yes look, I've posted the new code in the question.

Comment: fseek wants as argument the entire file content? I guess I can replace my while loop with one line of code?

Comment: Erm... no. Basically you `fopen` the file, and while you're not at (the end of the file - 4 bytes) you `fseek` to `offset` and `fgets` a `char*` with size 4. Repeat until done, serve hot with spicy sauce.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I practiced plain old C-style file reading, but basically, there it goes...

```
file handle = fopen('/var/mobile/...', 'r');
char *buf = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
long offset = 0;
while (1) {
   fseek(handle, ++offset);
   ret = fgets(handle, 4, &buf); // returns NULL on EOF
   if (ret) {
      if (buf[0] == 'E' && ...) {
         // Your logic goes here
         break;
      }
   }
   else
      break;
}
fclose(handle);
```

Of course this is all pseudo-code, feel free to investigate or correct me.

Comment: Hi, this code seems to write into the file on the hard disk: I opened it after running the code and it is empty. Do you maybe know why?

Comment: `fgets` reads files from disk; to write you use `fputs`. The code I've given is unusable as-is, as I said it's pseudo-code to give you the general idea of low-level file access.

Comment: ok, I solved the writing issue thanks. However, the encoding seems to be different and it can't find the string EXTH. I've added the 2 codes (objective-c and c) in the question for comparison. The above one, works (although it is slow).